# R Stacked Bar Chart: How to change the order of geom text labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

The geom Texts labels are automatically in decreasing order instead of the data frame.

The question is concerning this part of the snippet "geom_text(aes(label = Freq)..."

Here you can clearly see the that the order is not followed by geom_text. But Frequency descreasing in all categories.

```
ggplot(df_beine_clan, aes(x = Var2, y = Freq, fill = Var1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), vjust = 0, size = 5, nudge_y = 2, nudge_x = -0.5)
```

See Freq Order

How to command that the order should not be changed when rendered on the bar chart?

Comment: Provide the output of `dput(df_beine_clan)`

Comment: structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), levels = c("Evil Sunz", "Goffs", "Snakebites"), class = "factor"), 
    Var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("O-Beine", 
    "S-Beine", "X-Beine"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(8L, 16L, 
    11L, 18L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `position_stack` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_beine_clan, aes(x = Var2, y = Freq, fill = Var1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question without having a MWE is a bit tricky. Hence, as Julien mentioned, an output of `dput(df_beine_clan)` would be helpful.

I tried to recreate an example, but this might not be applicable to the structure of your data. It might give you an example, however how to tackle the problem. I have created a column in the data table, that contains the `label` I think you want to add to your plot. Having a separate column gives you more flexibility inside ggplot.

```
library(tidyverse)

Group <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
Value <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12)
Response <- c("Yes","No","Maybe","Yes","No","Maybe")
label <- Value
df <- data.frame(Group, Value, Response, label)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Response)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Changing the variable `label` to `label <- sort(Value, decreasing = T)` or `label <- c("Blue", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red")` gives you the two figures below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I thought that attached a picture of it. 
I edited my question.
The second stacked bar is randomly ordered from mist to least, so bear in mind the first and last bar concerning my issue.